# srcCompact attribute not working using view style

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

I'm trying to use the attribute srcCompat in style:

```
<item name="app:srcCompat">@drawable/ic_work</item>
```

Android Studio says nothing about it but when compiling I get this error:

> error: style attribute 'app:attr/srcCompat' not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 'app:attr/srcCompat'
>   not found.,
>   sources=[D:...\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2888],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: On which component do you apply this style?

Comment: To a simple ImageView!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the attribute within an style. Hence you don't need the `app`-prefix:

```
<item name="srcCompat">@drawable/ic_work</item>
```

Comment: And this solved my problem! Thanks everyone for responding so fast to my question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below code into gradle `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use AppCompatImageView to use `srcCompat` instead of ImageView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Yes, good advice (I forget everytime!) but still getting the same error!

Comment: I would not recommend to use the AppCompatImageView directly. The system replaces the default ImageView with this one, once it is required. -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView